# A colleague won't tell me her name preference?

Tags: socializing

I have a colleague, who has been called by 2 different names. Her middle name was not what I was used to, but recently another colleague referred to her by her middle name.

When I asked said collegue which name she prefers, she replies simply that "Anything is fine".

I wonder if I should probe further, or leave it be?

Comment: Go with however she signs her emails.

Comment: @DavidK or answers the phone

Comment: If you're more caught up on what to call her than she is... you've got too much time on your hands.

Comment: Everyone I work with calls me Doyle. Most of my friend call me DJ. Some call me "Deej" when they are feeling really lazy. Some friends also call me Doyle. I couldn't care less what any of them call me.

Comment: "Anything" it is then.

Comment: it's possible the middle name is reserved for those she feels closer to, but she's embarrassed to tell you that. Keep calling her what you always did; one day she may ask you to use another name but don't push it.

Comment: @KateGregory - Do you know if that's the case in India ?

Comment: @Adel My only experience there is with people who go by initials only except with their closest friends who know what the initials stand for. But India is a large place, I wouldn't generalize

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I wonder if I should probe further, or leave it be?

Taking people at their word is usually a good thing unless there are overriding reasons which I don't see here. So I wouldn't make a big deal out of it.

Depending on culture some people may have several names used interchangeably. In my culture using a second name is not unusual, or even a transliteration of a hard to pronounce name, or using someones cultural title bestowed on them by their family chiefs.

Other people are known by different names by friends or family, so for instance my Fathers name is John Peter, but he was called Peter by nearly everyone to differentiate himself from his father who was also John.

In any case I wouldn't bother with it or even try to find out the reason, if your colleague is comfortable with it, I would just call her by her first name. Or whatever she is using formally.